# Создать абстрактный класс Deposit и объявить в нем:

Tags: c#

Создать абстрактный класс Deposit и объявить в нем:
• Государственные деньги только для чтения Amount (сумма депозита)
• Публичное целочисленное свойство только для чтения Period (время депозита в месяцах)
• Конструктор с параметрами depositAmount и
depositPeriod, который создает депозит объекта с указанной суммой на указанный период.
• Абстрактный метод Income, который возвращает денежную стоимость - сумму дохода от депозита.

Доход - это разница между суммой, снятой с депозита по истечении срока действия и
внесенная сумма.
Подскажите как правильно описать метод `Income`

```
class Deposit {
    public readonly decimal Amount;
 
    //TODO: Define public readonly property "Period" with int type.
    public readonly int Period;
 
    //TODO: Define constructor that gets "Amount" and "Period" and assigns them to its properties.
    protected Deposit(decimal amount,int period)
    {
        Amount = amount;
        Period = period;
    }
 
    //TODO: Define public abstract method "Income" that returns deposit profit depending on "Amount" and "Period".
    public abstract Income(decimal amount, int period)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Методы помеченные как ```abstract``` не могут содержать в себе реализацию. Задача точно правильно поставлена? Может Вам необходим модификатор ```virtual```?

Comment: Что, и проценты годовых не указаны нигде? Непонятно что тут вообще можно посчитать без процентов.

Comment: @CrazyElf Просто вопрос в котором необходимо решить дз/лабораторку за автора, думаю, автор и сам не в курсе, указан ли % или нет

Comment: @AlAvenger Да её невозможно решить, ТЗ не полное! )

Comment: класс Deposit должен быть абстрактным `abstract class Deposit` согласно условию, а метод inome и прочая логика реализуется уже после наследования. Я так понял.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Deposit 
    {
            public readonly decimal Amount;
         
            //TODO: Define public readonly property "Period" with int type.
            public readonly int Period;
         
            //TODO: Define constructor that gets "Amount" and "Period" and assigns them to its properties.
            protected Deposit(decimal amount,int period)
            {
                Amount = amount;
                Period = period;
            }
         
            //TODO: Define public abstract method "Income" that returns deposit profit depending on "Amount" and "Period".
            public abstract decimal Income(decimal amount, int period);
        }
```

Вот так правильно реализовывать абстрактный метод в абстрактном классе. Такие методы получают реализацию только после наследования.

```
//наследование
class ChildClass : Deposit
{
   public override decimal Income(decimal amount, int period)
    {
       //реализация после наследования
    }
}
```

Почитай про абстрактные классы и уточни условия задачи.

Comment: спасибо, да, разобрал и уже все решилось